# How to tell if socket is open in PHP?

Tags: php, sockets

I am required to maintain a few sockets that I opened with PHP and check those sockets at regular intervals. I am new to sockets in PHP;  I opened the sockets like this:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP); 
socket_connect($socket, $ip, $port);
```

Some of the sockets can get into a state where they don't return messages; these sockets only receive messages. **How can I tell if a socket is opened if the socket does not respond to a message?**

Comment: You should distinguish sockets which are "opened" e.g. OS allocates resources for those descriptors, and sockets which are "connected" to another sockets (for example server sockets on remote host). In this case question should be about "...if a socket CONNECTION is opened..." in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

> socket_sendto — Sends a message to a socket, whether it is connected or not

Seems like you could use [socket_sendto](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php) and send some 'ping' data to the remote host, then test the return value to determine if the socket is still established.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out?

Comment: What about a non blocking attempt to read from the socket? That should return either blank or false depending if it's connected or not. Will also generate a Warning I think but that can be disabled.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use the function: fsockopen()

Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php

or you could try to use the function: socket_create_listen()

Read this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.socket-create-listen.php

(this one is just experimental.)

and to check at regular intervals you could make it using a simple cron.